# PAnsiChar, invalid typecast

Tags: delphi

I have problem with casting Strings to AnsiChars, function looks like

```
function PI_CST(ID: LongInt;
            const szAxes: PAnsiChar;
            const szNames: PAnsiChar): Bool cdecl  ;
```

I want to use this funcion in this way:

```
bOk:=PI_CST(g_iD,'1',PAnsiChar(ComboBox1.Text));
```

but it doesn't work, when I call function in this way:`bOk:=PI_CST(g_iD,'1','M-511.DD1')` it works great (value beetween quotes is const), is there any way to use in this function with parameter choosen from ComboBox?

Comment: I guess you are having Unicode Delphi (2009 or above) and thus the `Text` property is of Unicode string type. If that is so, use `PAnsiChar(AnsiString(ComboBox1.Text))`.

Comment: @meller92 Whenever you ask about questions that could relate to Unicode, you should include the Delphi version in your tags. Supposing that you use XE7 then the tags for this question should be `delphi delphi-xe7`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PAnsiChar(ComboBox1.Text)
```

This tells the compiler to interpret the string returned by the `Text` property as though it were a pointer to 8 bit ANSI characters. If the string is a Unicode string, then the cast is not valid because the underlying buffer is encoded with 16 bit text.

You need to convert the string to ANSI before casting:

```
PAnsiChar(AnsiString(ComboBox1.Text))
```

Comment: So if I want to cast from AnsiChar array to PWideChar first I must cast this array to AnsiString too?

Comment: No. If you want `PWideChar` then you write `PChar(ComboBox1.Text)` or `PWideChar(ComboBox1.Text)` if you prefer. I prefer the former since to me `PChar` always matches `string`.

Comment: I think about something like: `Application.MessageBox(PWideChar(AnsiString(puffer)),'Error',0);` where puffer is array of AnsiChars

Comment: `Application.MessageBox(pBuffer)` should be fine. The compiler knows what `pBuffer` is and will convert appropriately.

Comment: Actually, `PWideChar(AnsiString(puffer))` is the same error as you have in your question, but the other way around. If `puffer` contains AnsiChars then you do: `PWideChar(UnicodeString(puffer))`. The `UnicodeString(puffer)` cast converts `puffer` to a wide character string and of that, you can take the pointer using `PWideChar(...)`. But, as @DavidHeffernan says, if the type of `puffer` is known, and `Application.MessageBox()` expects a string parameter, the conversion will be done automatically. But this does not apply to pointers like `PAnsiChar` or `PWideChar`.